# I am having a hard time using GTK to draw text

Tags: c, gtk

I try to type this code to display text on the screen but there is no text when I compile and then open the compiled app. Why wont this work? I am using C  and Linux and I am trying to use gtk header files. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void helloWorld (GtkWidget *wid, GtkWidget *win) {
    GtkWidget *dialog = NULL;

    dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (GTK_WINDOW (win), GTK_DIALOG_MODAL, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE, "Hello World! My name is ****");
    gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (dialog), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *button = NULL;
    GtkWidget *win = NULL;  
    GtkWidget *vbox = NULL;

    /* Initialize GTK+ */
    g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, (GLogFunc) gtk_false, NULL);
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, g_log_default_handler, NULL);

    /* Create the main window */
    win = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW (win), 400, 300);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (win), 8);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (win), "The stupid GTK test");
    gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (win), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_realize (win);
    g_signal_connect (win, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

    /* Create a vertical box with buttons*/

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new (TRUE, 6);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (win), vbox);

    button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_DIALOG_INFO);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (helloWorld), (gpointer) win);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_CLOSE);
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", gtk_main_quit, NULL);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    GtkWidget *view;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    GtkTextIter start, end;
    PangoFontDescription *font_desc;
    GdkColor color;
    GtkTextTag *tag;

    view = gtk_text_view_new ();

    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (view));

    gtk_text_buffer_set_text (buffer, "Hello, this is some text", -1);

    /* Change default font throughout the widget */
    font_desc = pango_font_description_from_string ("Serif 15");
    gtk_widget_modify_font (view, font_desc);
    pango_font_description_free (font_desc);

    /* Change default color throughout the widget */
    gdk_color_parse ("green", &color);
    gtk_widget_modify_text (view, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);

    /* Change left margin throughout the widget */
    gtk_text_view_set_left_margin (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (view), 30);

    /* Use a tag to change the color for just one part of the widget */
    tag = gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (buffer, "blue_foreground",
                            "foreground", "blue", NULL);  
    gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset (buffer, &start, 7);
    gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset (buffer, &end, 12);
    gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag (buffer, tag, &start, &end);
    /*Enter the main loop */
    gtk_widget_show_all (win);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make this work? I want it to display text when I compile and then open. I tried several things and none of them work.

Comment: @JeffSchaller just buttons, no text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use ALL that code just to draw text? You know, you can draw text in a much simpler way than that.

For text, in the least amount of code, looks like this:

```
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Window), gtk_label_new("Hello, World"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the textbox to someplace on the window, where it would be actually displayed, like so

```
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), view, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
```

(must be after view is defined and before the show_all call).
If you look at your code you see that this call is made for all other widgets which appear. Your problem is in fact not specific to drawing text.

Comment: Not a GTK expert, but I guess the most sensible place to insert it would probably be after the `gtk_text_buffer_set_text` line?

Comment: Man I was such a nub. In reality I don't need that much code to draw one text label